# How to make xml nodes open and close on the same line when they have no children?

Tags: c#, xml

I am working with a large XML file and want to shorten it a bit.
I currently have many occurrences of something like this:

```
<column name="Name">
</column>
```

Since column does not have child nodes, I would like it to be

```
<column name="Name"/>
```

The xml is produced by FluentNHibernate configuration

```
Fluently.Configure(configuration)
    .Mappings(
          m=>m.FluentMappings
              .Add(...)
              .ExportTo("myXmlFile"))
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

The column node is created for

```
Map(x=>x.Name);
```

in my ClassMap.

Can I somehow use System.Xml classes to rewrite it to file one line for each childless node)?

Comment: Please be more specific. *How* exactly do you produce the XML? Show your code.

Comment: This depends on the xml generation process - it will determine whether to use a self closing tag or a full tag.  What libraries are you using to generate the xml?

Comment: I don't think I want to modify FluentNH code, so what I want to do is first read the file FNH produces and load it into, for example an XmlDocument. Then rewrite it with self-closing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably can't change how the XML is created, you can load it into an `XDocument` and make the changes you need.  By default it will be loaded ignoring whitespace - this will rewrite this:

```
<column name="Name">
</column>
```

as this:

```
<column name="Name"></column>
```

This is because it sees it has a value of `""`.  To get rid of this, you need to clear the content of those that have an empty string as their value.

```
string xml = "..."

var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var emptyElements = document.Descendants()
    .Where(e => !e.Nodes().Any());

foreach (var element in emptyElements)
{
    element.RemoveNodes();
}

xml = document.ToString();
```

The code looks odd (what nodes are we removing from an element with no nodes?!), but this makes sure the internal `content` field is `null` where, in this case, it was `""`.  The end result is this:

```
<column name="Name" />
```